What are the differences in different shock absorbers?
I know it depends on a number of factors, but how much better is other shock systems compared to the "low end" ones that are not replaceable and have no shock under the seat that I  have seen?
I would mainly be riding on sidewalks or flat roadways.
Thanks.

The question is very general, but considering your other question (hardtail stored outside), the best shock absorber for sidewalks and flat roadways are good/supple tires at the right pressure (tires are often overinflated) and no suspended fork. Good suspensions require more care/periodic maintenance than entry-level ones to maintain their performance, and IMHO, the tradeoff is not worth it for the use-case you describe.

In addition to being very general, your question is a little unclear to begin with. Are you asking about the differences between low end and high end suspension parts or the differences between various suspension layouts (independent of what parts you use with them)?
